# Consulta Insert - Select MYSQL error

Tags: mysql

Necesito saber qué está mal en la siguiente consulta:

```
INSERT INTO tb_outdoors (excursion_id, confirmacion_nro, servicio_fecha,
servicio_nombre) VALUES ('150', (SELECT confirmacion_nro, servicio_fecha, 
servicio_nombre FROM tb_outdoors WHERE tb_outdoors.id in(6235) ))
```

El error que me da es el siguiente:

> Operando debe tener 1 columna(s)

Comment: No entiendo lo que intentas hacer pudieras explicar mejor por favor ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No es válido hacer una subconsulta directamente en una sentencia de `INSERT`, pero lo que si puedes hacer es una consulta de inserción de la siguiente manera:

```
INSERT INTO tb_outdoors (excursion_id, confirmacion_nro, servicio_fecha, servicio_nombre) 
SELECT '150', 
       confirmacion_nro, 
       servicio_fecha, 
       servicio_nombre 
       FROM tb_outdoors 
       WHERE tb_outdoors.id in (6235)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias !!

Answer (score 2):

Considero que debes escribir varias consultas SELECT, 1 por columna. Así:

```
INSERT INTO tb_outdoors (excursion_id, 
confirmacion_nro, servicio_fecha, servicio_nombre) 
VALUES ('150', (SELECT confirmacion_nro FROM 
tb_outdoors WHERE tb_outdoors.id in(6235) ), (SELECT 
servicio_fecha FROM tb_outdoors WHERE tb_outdoors.id 
in(6235) ), (SELECT servicio_nombre FROM tb_outdoors 
WHERE tb_outdoors.id in(6235) ));
```